# xcode error -1012 when request http (server using ssl redirection)

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, ssl, request

I try to request web service as HTTP in Advanced rest client (Google chrome  extension) and then I see server redirected to https and it is success I have data but I try to this from xcode getting error -1012 in my `info.plist` file :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

and I use the following code:-

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0];
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Is there anybody help me?

Comment: when i change plis like this <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
<key>http://subdomain.somdomain.gov.tr</key>
<dict>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.1</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</dict> i got App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.